# LTspice RF530 VDMOS component

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice

I am new to this forum and also knew to the program LTspice. I want to create a IRF530 VMOS component and have found a model for it;

.model IRF530 VDMOS(Rg=3 Vto=4 Rd=50m Rs=12m Rb=60m Kp=5 lambda=.01 Cgdmax=1n Cgdmin=.26n Cgs=.2n Cjo=.4n Is=52p mfg=International_Rectifier Vds=100 Ron=160m Qg=26n)

I have managed to find a page that describes all the abbreviations above (http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_6.htm). I have however no idea about how to create this IRF530 VDMOS. I appreciate any help and if there is a way around it :)

Comment: There already is a model for `IRF530`. When browsing the models, click on the `Part No.` table header to sort the entries alphabetically, it will make things easier.

Comment: Not only that but your model is actually just a copy/paste of an older version of the built-in LTspice model.  Actually, the newer one is better because it defines `ksubthres`, so please just use as described by @aconcernedcitizen.

Comment: Thanks @aconcerned for your reply, I was able to find the component!